# How to add an icon to a Win32API window in a CMake Project

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am making a C++ framework that offers window, events, input and rendering to serve as a base for all my 2D & 3D simulations. Since I am making it with native API's, I was wondering if anyone knows how to change the icon on the window in Windows (without an rc file if possible since I am building with CMake & Clang).

Tried this:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc = {}
wc.hIcon = LoadIconA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE("icon.ico"));
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you don't want to use a resource script you'll have to load the icon at run time (using [`LoadImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew), for example). CMake doesn't need to know about this beyond making sure the icon file winds up in a location the application is looking for.

Comment: @IInspectable can you show me an example of how to use or a reference to an example please?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it *via* this (as IInspectable suggested, I loaded the icon *via* `LoadImage`):

```
HICON hIcon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(
    mConnection,
    "icon.ico", // Path to your icon file or
                // resource ID
    IMAGE_ICON, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON),
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON), LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTSIZE));

if(hIcon) {
    SendMessageA(mHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG,
                 reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hIcon));
    SendMessageA(mHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL,
                 reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hIcon));
}
```

Comment: You don't strictly have to send `WM_SETICON` messages. You can use the `HICON` returned from `LoadImage` to populate the `hIcon` and `hIconSm` fields of the `WNDCLASSEX` structure as well.